# Prepositions used with "command line" and "shell"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, computing, collocation

I found the following variations on the use of "command line" and "shell" in computing and wonder which are correct and how to use them appropriately.

- *Command line*: is it "at the command line" or "on the command line"?
- *Shell*: is it "in a shell", inside a shell", "at a shell" or "on a shell"?

My English teacher once jokingly said that with prepositions it's not only knowledge but sometimes also a good portion of luck for those who aren't native speakers.

Comment: See  [Difference between “on the command line” and “at the command line”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/45786),

Comment: @jwpat7 this I must have missed. Thank you! :)

Comment: Also see ELL's [When I should use “into”, “in”, “by” and “through”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4200),  re running commands at a prompt.

Comment: I like what your English teacher said. I also like to mention on occasion that there are some instances where there is no "right" preposition, but two or three that might be valid. "We met him at/in the bowling alley, on/at Lane 12," e.g.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "on the command line" and "at the command line"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45786/difference-between-on-the-command-line-and-at-the-command-line)

Comment: If you are familiar with preposition use, this should be easy. This question is no exception to the general rules and conventions of preposition use. However, a correct understanding of the concept of *command line* and *shell* is required to chose the appropriate preposition in the given context. See e.g., tchrist below http://english.stackexchange.com/a/110264/14666

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One normally runs commands ***in*** a shell, not the others that you have listed.

However, if you had the shell’s process ID and sent that PID a signal of some sort, one could be said to have run the *kill*(1) command ***on*** that shell, in the sense of against it. Presumably the shell that you ran your kill *in* and the one you ran it *on* were different shells.